# Print shell output for each item in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to execute several commands using the "with_items" construct in Ansible. If a command failed I want to print its standard output. I have made a minimal example to illustrate the problem.

```
- action: shell echo {{item}}
  with_items:
  - 1
  - 2
  register: task

- debug: var=item.stdout_lines
  with_items: "{{task.results}}"
```

The problem is that not only stdout line is printed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

> If a command failed I want to print its standard output.

If shell exits with a non-zero status then Ansible will exit on that error.

That being said, if you change

```
- debug: var=item.stdout_lines
  with_items: "{{task.results}}"
```

to

```
- debug: var=item
  with_items: "{{ task.results | map(attribute='stdout_lines') | list }}"
```

that will print all the lines of output without all the other info that is in the results dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html).

```
---
  - hosts: all

    tasks:
      - block:
        - name: test
          shell: date; /bin/false
          register: cmd_reg
        rescue:
          - debug: var=cmd_reg
          # fail the build ?
```

Output:

```
ap test.yml -c local -i 'localhost, '

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [test] ********************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "date; /bin/false", "delta": "0:00:00.011686", "end": "2016-11-23 11:43:26.554559", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-11-23 11:43:26.542873", "stderr": "/bin/sh: /bin/false: No such file or directory", "stdout": "Wed 23 Nov 2016 11:43:26 GMT", "stdout_lines": ["Wed 23 Nov 2016 11:43:26 GMT"], "warnings": []}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cmd_reg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "date; /bin/false",
        "delta": "0:00:00.011686",
        "end": "2016-11-23 11:43:26.554559",
        "failed": true,
        "rc": 127,
        "start": "2016-11-23 11:43:26.542873",
        "stderr": "/bin/sh: /bin/false: No such file or directory",
        "stdout": "Wed 23 Nov 2016 11:43:26 GMT",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Wed 23 Nov 2016 11:43:26 GMT"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Things to notice:

1. you'll need to fail your build if you need the build to fail manually cause this playbook assumes everything is all right.
2. Use the [anwser above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40708639/2599522) to print out everything you need - this is a simple illustration of blocks.